# Comparing multiple columns of a massive DataFrame with complex duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a massive dataframe `df` with around 10 million rows:

```
df.sort_values(['pair','x1','x2'])


x1    x1gen    x2     x2gen     y1     y1gen     y2     y2gen      pair
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A     male     H      female    a      male      d      male       0
A     male     W      male      a      male      d      male       0         (*)
A     male     KK     female    a      male      d      male       0         (**)
B     female   C      male      a      male      d      male       0         (-)
B     female   W      male      a      male      d      male       0         (*)
B     female   BB     female    a      male      d      male       0
B     female   KK     female    a      male      d      male       0         (**)
F     male     W      male      a      male      d      male       0         (*)
A     male     T      female    b      female    d      male       1
A     male     BB     female    b      female    d      male       1
B     female   C      male      b      female    d      male       1         (-)
D     male     E      male      b      female    d      male       1
A     male     C      male      b      female    e      female     2
...
```

Each column can be explained by the following:

- `x1gen` is a gender data of `x1`, `x2gen` is of `x2`, and so on.
- `x1` cites `y1` and `x2` cites `y2`.
- Each pair of `y1` and `y2` is assigned a unique `pair` value.

My objective is to find four values per unique `pair`:

1. `male` citing `male`
2. `male` citing `female`
3. `female` citing `male`
4. `female` citing `female`

where, each citation network should not be counted more than once.

For example, in the given sample, `x2 = W` is appeared three times in `pair = 0` (see `(*)`), so it should be counted once, not three times. Same applies to `x2 = KK` in `pair = 0` (see `(**)`). However, we can count the same reference if it is a new pair. (`C -> d` in `(-)` is counted separately once per `pair = 0` and `pair = 1`)

Hence, for the first pair `pair = 0`, the objective values are:

1. `male` citing `male` = 4 (`A -> a, F -> a, W -> d, C -> d`)
2. `male` citing `female` = 0
3. `female` citing `male` = 4 (`B -> a, H -> d, KK -> d, BB -> d`)
4. `female` citing `female` = 0

What I initially did was using a `for` loop and a set of `if` loops and creating four lists separately for `x1` and `x2`:

```
mm = [1]
mf = [0]
fm = [0]
ff = [0]

mm1 = 1
mf1 = 0
fm1 = 0
ff1 = 0

for i in range(1, len(df)):
  if df['pair'][i] == df['pair'][i-1]:
    if df['x1'][i] != df['x1'][i-1]:
      if df['x1gen'][i] == 'male':
        if df['y1gen'][i] == 'male':
          mm1 += 1
        else:
          mf1 += 1
      else:
        if df['y1gen'][i] == 'male':
          fm1 += 1
        else:
          ff1 += 1
...
```

and the gist is analogous (the code itself is MANY lines long, but just a repetition of those lines). As one can tell, this is HIGHLY inefficient (takes around 120 minutes).

What is the optimal way to find such values without having to do a highly inefficient string-matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
import io  
import re
import pandas as pd

# this just recreates the dataframe 
s = '''
x1    x1gen    x2     x2gen     y1     y1gen     y2     y2gen      pair
A     male     H      female    a      male      d      male       0
A     male     W      male      a      male      d      male       0
A     male     KK     female    a      male      d      male       0
B     female   C      male      a      male      d      male       0
B     female   W      male      a      male      d      male       0
B     female   BB     female    a      male      d      male       0
B     female   KK     female    a      male      d      male       0
F     male     W      male      a      male      d      male       0
A     male     T      female    b      female    d      male       1
A     male     BB     female    b      female    d      male       1
B     female   C      male      b      female    d      male       1
D     male     E      male      b      female    d      male       1
A     male     C      male      b      female    e      female     2
'''

s = re.sub(r" +", " ", s)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep=" ")
print(df)
```

It gives:

```
   x1   x1gen  x2   x2gen y1   y1gen y2   y2gen  pair
0   A    male   H  female  a    male  d    male     0
1   A    male   W    male  a    male  d    male     0
2   A    male  KK  female  a    male  d    male     0
3   B  female   C    male  a    male  d    male     0
4   B  female   W    male  a    male  d    male     0
5   B  female  BB  female  a    male  d    male     0
6   B  female  KK  female  a    male  d    male     0
7   F    male   W    male  a    male  d    male     0
8   A    male   T  female  b  female  d    male     1
9   A    male  BB  female  b  female  d    male     1
10  B  female   C    male  b  female  d    male     1
11  D    male   E    male  b  female  d    male     1
12  A    male   C    male  b  female  e  female     2
```

Counting citation pairs:

```
# count x1-> y1 pairs
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['x1', 'y1', 'pair'])
c1 = (df1['x1gen'] + '_' + df1['y1gen']).value_counts()

# count x2-> y2 pairs
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['x2', 'y2', 'pair'])
c2 = (df2['x2gen'] + '_' + df2['y2gen']).value_counts()

# add results
c1.add(c2, fill_value=0).astype(int)
```

This gives:

```
female_female    1
female_male      6
male_female      4
male_male        6
```

Computing results for each pair separately:

```
def cit_count(g):

    # count x2-> y2 pairs
    df1 = g.drop_duplicates(subset=['x1', 'y1'])
    c1 = (df1['x1gen'] + '_' + df1['y1gen']).value_counts()

    # count x2-> y2 pairs
    df2 = g.drop_duplicates(subset=['x2', 'y2'])
    c2 = (df2['x2gen'] + '_' + df2['y2gen']).value_counts()

    # add results
    return c1.add(c2, fill_value=0)

print(df.groupby('pair').apply(cit_count).unstack().fillna(0).astype(int))
```

It gives:

```
      female_female  female_male  male_female  male_male
pair                                                    
0                 0            4            0          4
1                 1            2            2          2
2                 0            0            2          0
```

Comment: This code seems to capture the correct total tally of each category, but is there a way to get such values for each pair? For example, for pair `0`, the numbers are 0, 4, 0, 4, and for pair `1`, the numbers are 1, 2, 2, 2, etc.